# I would like to give special promotion for the first 100 posts in my blog? Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Tags: posts, query-posts, post-meta

My website is a multi author blog. I would like to give special promotion for the first 100 published posts in my blog?

What is the proper way to implement it? I mean should i add some meta value for first 100 published posts and then query it later using that meta value?

If yes can anyone tell me how? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

Run an SQL query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' AND `post_type` = 'post' GROUP BY `post_author` ORDER BY `post_date` ASC  LIMIT 100
```

The above will give you the first 100 authors to have a post published. or:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_status` = 'publish' AND `post_type` = 'post' ORDER BY `post_date` ASC  LIMIT 100
```

this will give you the first 100 published posts